# Why I can`t close this modal without changes or save changes?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I pass a task as props and create a variable in the component that stores the initial value. When I click on the "Close" button and the values are entered in the textarea, I need not to save the changes, but if I click on the "Save" button, then save them. How can this be done, otherwise nothing works for me

```
<template lang="pug">
    .modal-task(:style="{display: showDetailsModal}")
        .modal-task-details
            .task
                .name(v-show="show")
                    |Name: {{task.name}}
                .text(v-show="!show")
                    textarea(v-model='updatedTask.name')
                .status
                    |Status: {{task.status}}
                .deadline
                    |Deadline: {{task.time}}
                .description(v-show="show")
                  |description: {{task.description1}}
                .text(v-show="!show" @change="handleChange")
                    textarea(v-model='updatedTask.description1')
            button(class='add-task' v-on:click="show=!show" v-show="show") Edit
            button(class='add-task' v-on:click="show=!show" v-show="!show" @click="closeForm()") Close
            button(class='add-task' v-show="showSaveButton" @click="saveTask(task)") Save
    </template>
    
    <script lang="ts">
    import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
    import { emitter } from '../main'
    
    export default defineComponent({
      name: 'task-details-modal',
      props: ['showDetailsModal', 'task'],
      data () {
        return {
          show: true,
          showSaveButton: true,
          updatedTask: {}
        }
      },
      methods: {
        closeForm () {
          emitter.emit('close')
          console.log(this.updatedTask)
        },
        saveTask () {
          this.updatedTask = this.task
          emitter.emit('close')
        },
        handleChange () {
          this.showSaveButton = true
        }
      },
      created () {
        this.updatedTask = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.task))
      }
    })
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save the data, you need to emit an another event, which will call the saveMethod function and then close the dialog from the save method in case of successful action.

Currently, you're emitting close event on the save and close action which you need to separate it.